# Headphone volume low

Tags: headphones, sound-volume

This just started happening recently. When I plug my headphones in, I get full high fidelity volume for a fraction of a second and then it becomes significantly muted.

I've checked "Sound" in Preferences to ensure that I've not reduced my system volume.

Any other ideas on what might be causing this?

UPDATE:

- Tried restarting (multiple times)
- Tried resetting NVRAM to no avail

System Specs: MBP 15" Mid-2014 on Yosemite

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: nope, not yet, please let me know if you did!

Answer (score 1):

I waited a couple of days and randomly I tried playing a video and the sound worked perfectly fine. I would just try waiting a couple of days like I did.